# show hide with same class name on click

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to build simple list with some question and answers. When the question is clicked the answer is shown below,on page load it is hidden. I'm using the same class for all the questions,so the problem is when i click to expand the answer,all the below answers is getting expanded. How can i solve that? Below is the script.
Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/36Y5w/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.faq_content').hide();

    $('.faq_circle').click(function(){
        var $target = $('.faq_content');
        if( $target.is(':visible') ){
            $target.slideUp(400,function(){
                $target.addClass('feature-folded');
            });
            $(this).text('+');
        }
        else{
            $target.removeClass('feature-folded');
            $target.slideDown();
            $(this).text('-');
        }
    });

 });
</script>
```

Comment: feel free to ask me if any issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.faq_circle').click(function(){
        var $target = $(this).next().children('.faq_content');
        if( $target.is(':visible') ){
            $target.slideUp(400,function(){
                $target.addClass('feature-folded');
            });
            $(this).text('+');
        }
        else{
            $target.removeClass('feature-folded');
            $target.slideDown();
            $(this).text('-');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of targeting all elements with class '.faq_content', just select the next element with that class. That should do the trick.

```
var $target = $(this).next('.faq_content');
```

Comment: I had a look at this and it doesnt seem to work, although @Jain answer seems to be correct.